# Why a new sub-directory gets created while pushing to Github

Tags: python, git, github, version-control, jekyll

When pushing my source code to Github repo, the entire source code gets stored inside a newly made repo which I don't want.

This is the current directory structure (Image 1):

[image]

Also, this is what it looks like in github repo:

[image]

I want to know why this is happening as I don't want a new sub-directory and instead move the contents up the directory just as it is in image 1.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have done `git init` within a folder containing your folder `1pani.github.io` and hence now you have:

- `1pani.github.io/.git`
- `1pani.github.io/1pani.github.io/...`

What you can do is:

- `git clone https://github.com/1pani/1pani.github.io`
- move the entire content of the folder `1pani.github.io/1pani.github.io` to `1pani.github.io/`
- delete the now empty `1pani.github.io/1pani.github.io`
- you should have now things like `1pani.github.io/404.html`, ...